# Can an android phone harm windows network?

Tags: windows, attacks, appsec, phone

Is it a security issue if someone is able to login into windows domain through an android phone with admin credentials through something like ES file explorer? I read that usually androids cant run exe files so I feel like not much harm can be done without tools like cmd.exe

Comment: If anything, ```cmd``` would be the last tool I would use if I could. If I had to be on windows, I would try to use cygwin or some other bash simulator.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, any device that allows you access to a Windows network can be used to compromise that network. It doesn't matter that an android phone can't run exe files. I can grab tokens, attack files, databases...etc

And similar to @iismathwizard, I wouldn't expect to ever use cmd.exe on any device I was using to attack a Windows network. I may run the cmd.exe on a compromised Windows box, but to do that I'd have already connected to that box, and I can do that from any device I like with RDP/SSH/telnet/whatever